# How to decode custom type inside dictionary value with JSON?

Tags: json, swift, decodable

my JSON:
https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js
my code:

```
struct CoinData: Decodable {
    let Valute: [String: CoinInfo]
}

struct CoinInfo: Decodable {
    let Name: String
    let Value: Double
}
```

```
if let safeData = data {
    if let coinData = self.parseJSON(safeData) {
    print(coinData) 
    }
}
```

```
func parseJSON(_ data: Data) -> [String: CoinInfo]? {

    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
     do {
        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(CoinData.self, from: data)
        return decodedData.Valute

     } catch {
        delegate?.didFailWithError(error: error)
        return nil
    }
}
```

In debug console following gets printed:

```
["PLN": CurrencyConverter.CoinInfo(Name: "X", Value: 19.6678), ...]
```

This way I can't reach `Name` and `Value` properties of a coin. What's wrong?

Comment: "This way I can't reach Name and Value properties of a coin." You can. What code did you use to try to access them? And what error did that code produce?

Comment: Which property of which coin did you expect `coinData.Valute` to give you? In other words, which property (`Name` or `Value`) of which coin are you trying to access by using `coinData.Valute`?

Comment: I am going to do for-loop to check if a key contains certain symbols. If it does - I will need to be able to access to both `Name` and `Value`. So it does not really matter which one.

Comment: I tried `coinData.values[0]` - "Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Dictionary<String, CoinInfo>.Index'". I also tried: `coinData.Valute/CoinInfo/Name` - "Value of type '[String : CoinInfo]' has no member ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am going to do for-loop to check if a key contains certain symbols. If it does - I will need to be able to access to both Name and Value

You don't actually need a for loop. Since `coinData` is a dictionary, you can use its subscript, together with optional binding to do this. For example, to check if the key `"PLN"` exists, and access its name and value:

```
if let coinInfo = coinData["PLN"] {
    print(coinInfo.Name)
    print(coinInfo.Value)
} else {
    // "PLN" does not exist
}
```

Comment: What a magic! Thanks a lot! The problem was that I was treating it as an array so I was referring to an index and not a key

Answer (score 0):

StoyBoard

[image]

Code

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

// MARK: - CoinData
struct CoinData: Codable {
    let date, previousDate: String
    let previousURL: String
    let timestamp: String
    let valute: [String: Valute]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case date = "Date"
        case previousDate = "PreviousDate"
        case previousURL = "PreviousURL"
        case timestamp = "Timestamp"
        case valute = "Valute"
    }
}

// MARK: - Valute
struct Valute: Codable {
    let id, numCode, charCode: String
    let nominal: Int
    let name: String
    let value, previous: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "ID"
        case numCode = "NumCode"
        case charCode = "CharCode"
        case nominal = "Nominal"
        case name = "Name"
        case value = "Value"
        case previous = "Previous"
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
    var getCoinData = [CoinData]()
    var coinNameArr = [String]()
    var coinDataArr = [Valute]()

    @IBOutlet weak var tblDataList: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        getData()
    }

    func getData()
    {
        let url = "https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js"
                        
        AF.request(url, method: .get, encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
            let json = response.data
            do{
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                self.getCoinData = [try decoder.decode(CoinData.self, from: json!)]
                let response = self.getCoinData[0]
                if response.valute.count != 0 {
                    self.coinNameArr.removeAll()
                    self.coinDataArr.removeAll()
                    for (coinName, coinData) in response.valute {
                        self.coinNameArr.append(coinName)
                        self.coinDataArr.append(coinData)
                    }
                    self.tblDataList.reloadData()
                } else {
                }
            }catch let err{
                print(err)
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return coinDataArr.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
        let cell:coinTblCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellID", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! coinTblCell
    
        cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        cell.tintColor = .black

        let rowData = coinDataArr[indexPath.row]
        cell.lblName.text = rowData.name
        cell.lblValue.text = String(rowData.value)
    
        return cell
    }

}

class coinTblCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var lblName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblValue: UILabel!
}
```